# Filtering objects in AngularJS makes my string objects turns every string to a char array

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to filter data by a user input to a Textbox.

**When the page loads, all the data is displayed properly.**

[image: Data displayed properly]

**When typing text into the Textbox, all the string changes to a char array -**

[image: When typing text into the Textbox]

**After deleting the text in the Textbox the data looks like that -**

[image: After deleting the text in the Textbox]

This is the code I'm using -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FormatsApp" ng-controller="LinksController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <label class="label-to-left">Search Formats: </label>
    <input type="text" name="txtSearchFormats" ng-model="txtSearchFormats" />
    <div id="formatsBox">
        <div ng-repeat="i in items">{{ i.name | filter:txtSearchFormats }}</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Angualr -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var formatsApp = angular.module('FormatsApp', []);
        formatsApp.controller('LinksController', function LinksController($scope) {
            $scope.items = [{ name: "Hello" }, { name: "Goodbye" }];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is, you are using `filter` in expression. So instead of you need to use with `ng-repeat`

Use `<div ng-repeat="i in items | filter:txtSearchFormats">{{ i.name }}</div>`

[AngularJS filter directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FormatsApp" ng-controller="LinksController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <label class="label-to-left">Search Formats: </label>
    <input type="text" name="txtSearchFormats" ng-model="txtSearchFormats" />
    <div id="formatsBox">
        <div ng-repeat="i in items | filter:txtSearchFormats">{{ i.name   }}</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Angualr -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var formatsApp = angular.module('FormatsApp', []);
        formatsApp.controller('LinksController', function LinksController($scope) {
            $scope.items = [{ name: "Hello" }, { name: "Goodbye" }];
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter should be applied on ng-repeat not on the expression,

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in items  | filter:txtSearchFormats">{{ i.name }}</div>
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
  var formatsApp = angular.module('FormatsApp', []);
        formatsApp.controller('LinksController', function LinksController($scope) {
            $scope.items = [{ name: "Hello" }, { name: "Goodbye" }];
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="FormatsApp" ng-controller="LinksController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <label class="label-to-left">Search Formats: </label>
    <input type="text" name="txtSearchFormats" ng-model="txtSearchFormats" />
    <div id="formatsBox">
        <div ng-repeat="i in items  | filter:txtSearchFormats">{{ i.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Angualr -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```